# Creating several input boxes from df in Python - smartly

Tags: python, loops, ipywidgets

I'm trying to create an input form based on a Excel spreadsheet.
I use the spreadsheet to create a dataframe (which has 30 "products" listed)
I need to create a series of input boxes for each product on the list.
Currently I do this in a very inefficient way :

```
  product_1 = (ipw.Dropdown(options=barrier_list['Product Name'],
                   value = barrier_list['Product Name'][0],
                   description= barrier_list['ISIN'][0],
                   disabled=False,
                   layout = {'width':'350px'}))
  product_1.style.description_width = 'initial'

  units_1 = (ipw.IntText(value=for_table['Units'][0],
                   description='Units:',
                   disabled=False,
                   layout = {'width':'200px'}
                  ))

  price_1 = (ipw.FloatText(value=for_table['Price'][0],
                   description='Price:',
                   disabled=False,
                   layout = {'width':'200px'}
                  ))

  value_1 = (ipw.FloatText(value=0,
                   description='Value:',
                   disabled=False,
                   layout = {'width':'200px'}
                  ))

  HBox_1 = ipw.HBox([product_1,units_1,price_1, value_1])
```

Which creates exactly what I need for one line of the input sheet. To do the next line I copy this exact code again and change all the [0] to [1]. This goes on 30x.

I know this is a terrible way to do it but I cannot figure out how to use a loop to create the 30 lines (1 per product) of input boxes.

Comment: Not a solution, but just a pointer. You will probably need to iterate through your columns and then create the appropriate widget based on the dtype of the column in question, then append to a list as you go.

Answer (score 1):

The guidance worked. My solution was simple and along the lines of :

```
dd_list = []
for i in range(len(barrier_list['Product Name'])):
     dropdown = widgets.Text(description=barrier_list['ISIN'][i],
                           value=barrier_list['Product Name'][i])

     dd_list.append(dropdown)

VBox1 = widgets.VBox(dd_list)
  
VBox1
```

Just need to create the other boxes and add to the VBox.